# wkhtmltopdf: Set enableIntelligentShrinking to false from C API?

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

I want to set the enableIntelligentShrinking setting to false as documented [here](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/libwkhtmltox/pagesettings.html)  and mentioned [here](http://blog.gluga.com/2012/05/wkhtmltopdf-font-and-sizing-issues.html). I am using wkhtmltopdf from C code, not from the command line, so I need to know how to change this setting via the C API. I understand how to set global and object settings (wkhtmltopdf_set_global_setting and wkhtmltopdf_add_object) but I do not see how to set "web" settings. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer myself: it's an object setting. Use the same method as you would for any object setting:

```
wkhtmltopdf_global_settings * gs;
wkhtmltopdf_object_settings * os;
wkhtmltopdf_converter * c;

os = wkhtmltopdf_create_object_settings();
wkhtmltopdf_set_object_setting(os, "web.enableIntelligentShrinking", "false"); // <--- HERE WE GO
c = wkhtmltopdf_create_converter(gs);
wkhtmltopdf_add_object(c, os, NULL);
if (!wkhtmltopdf_convert(c))
        fprintf(stderr, "report's wkHTMLtoPDF: Conversion failed!");
```